# How can I create a normalized distribution for producing an hsl color array?

Tags: javascript, statistics, normalization, distribution

I am creating a heatmap, where paths of countries in an SVG get fill colors that are all a shade of red using HSL.

`colorC = "hsl(0,100%," + colorL + "%)"`

The map is working great by several different methods where the user selects his own color intensity manually, but I am wanting to improve the map by adding an "auto" feature that chooses a good color intensity based on the values of the dataset.

I have been playing with bell distributions and various forms of data normalization, but these are not really accomplishing the goal.  Here is a little more about the working method.

There are two datasets that I have to deal with, a master dataset for all entries, which shows a strong skew toward the UK, and a target subset which I am trying to map.  In my working method, I loop through the target subset, normalizing each countries data by the master dataset, multiplying each value by this manually selected `colorIntensity`.

`colorL = (100 - (100 * colorIntensity * countrySubset[i] / countryMasterset[i]))`

The default value is `colorIntensity = 1`, which works great for large subsets, but leaves everything largely whited out on smaller subsets.  Subset size changes a lot, and as subsets are nested and can be walked up or down via parents and children, an automatic `colorIntensity` value would be a great asset.

So, here is the statistics question that is beyond my abilities.  What type of normalization and/or distribution can help me show a nice distribution of colors that are never black `hsl(0,100%,0%)` and never white `hsl(0,100%,100%)`, but nicely distributed somewhere in the deep red `hsl(0,100%,25%)` to light pink `hsl(0,100%,99%)` range?  All zero values default to light gray.

For example, the following subset looks great at `colorIntensity = 20` (USA data is used for the math, but not displayed on the map, as the map only shows Europe):

`{ "Wales": 15, "USA": 11, "Netherlands": 1, "Ireland": 2, "England": 2 }`

While this next subset looks much better at `colorIntensity = 10` (this is a ggparent of the above):

`{ "Germany": 34, "Switzerland": 12, "England": 44, "France": 13, "Italy": 10, "Sweden": 1, "Poland": 1, "Wales": 25, "USA": 44, "Canada": 3, "Mexico": 1, "Austria": 1, "Belgium": 1, "Ukraine": 1, "Portugal": 1, "Netherlands": 1, "Ireland": 20, "Denmark": 1, "Czech Republic": 8, "Luxembourg": 1, "Russia": 1, "Northern Ireland": 5, "Scotland": 29, "Turkey": 1, "Spain": 1, "Finland": 4 }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I found the best solution, but I did find a solution that I like.  The solution has two components:  selecting an appealing `colorIntensity` and dealing with individual country extremes.

Putting my preferred manually selected `colorIntensity` values into Excel, I realized that they were inversely related, so I set the `colorIntenstiy` with a negative power function and a maximum value:

```
colorIntensity = 300 * Math.pow(subsetTotal,-0.57)
if(colorIntensity > 25) colorIntensity = 25
```

Then, to deal with cases where a single country dominated a data subset and cases were a country had some data, but not much, I also put maximums and minimums on those situations within the loop itself.

```
for (var i in countrySubset) {
    var countryNormalized = countrySubset[i] / countryMasterset[i],
        colorNormalized = colorIntensity * countryNormalized
    if(colorNormalized > 0.75) colorNormalized = 0.75
    if(colorNormalized < 0.01) colorNormalized = 0.01
    colorL = (100 - (100 * colorNormalized))
}
```

I am happy with the final results and hope this might help someone else dealing with javascript and normalized, standardized, or scaled data.